# Is there a way to overwrite vim's default command?

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to map `:bd` to `:bd!` using:

```
command! -nargs=* -complete=buffer bd :call bd!
```

but vim told me "User defined commands must start with an uppercase letter"

---

update solutions from answer:

```
cnoremap bd bd!
```

another way

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> bd getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'bd' ? 'bd!' : 'bd'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a "user-defined" command to wrap the target command, `bd` in your case. Then you have to let the command name start with an uppercase letter.

In fact, if I understand your requirement correctly, you want to always execute `bd!` when you type `bd` in command mode, then you can just create a mapping:

```
cnoremap bd bd!
```

In this way, when you type `:bd` the `!` will be there automatically.

#### P.S.

When you used `call`, you are calling a `function()` instead of a command.

Comment: I have seen [it recommended](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) that one should always use `cnoremap` instead of `cmap`.

Comment: @chepner thx, I've changed in answer.